# How to change `ping from` value when pinging Linux server?

Tags: linux, centos, kernel, ping, hostname

Content of hostname file in my server is:

```
# cat /etc/hostname
sub.mysite.com
```

But when I `ping` my CentOS 7 server it says:

```
# ping sub.mysite.com
64 bytes from sub ...
```

Even:

```
# ping ns1.mysite.com
    64 bytes from sub ...
```

How can I tell my server to have the following output when pinging?

```
64 bytes from sub.mysite.com ...
```

## UPDATE

For example on my client:

```
user@host:~$ ping ns1.mysite.com
PING ns1.mysite.com (x.x.x.x) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sub (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=7.88 ms
64 bytes from sub (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=5.86 ms
64 bytes from sub (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=4.99 ms
64 bytes from sub (x.x.x.x): icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=4.88 ms
```

I want to have full hostname (sub.mysite.com) rather than `sub`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ping` doesn't use `/etc/hostname` to resolve IP to name mappings, it uses the Name Service (`netns`) to do these translations. Incidentally, `/etc/hostname` is part of systemd:

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/hostname
systemd-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64
```

That short name you're seeing, `sub`, is coming from your `/etc/hosts` file via the Name Service. If you use `strace` you can see how `ping` is finding `sub`:

```
$ strace -s 2000 ping -c1 www.google.com |& grep /etc/host
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
```

So the easy way to solve your problem is to put the name of your server as you want `ping` to display it in your `/etc/hosts` file.

#### Example

```
$ ping -c1 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.141.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from vl-in-f99.1e100.net (74.125.141.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=109 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 109.903/109.903/109.903/0.000 ms
Now if we were to add that IP, 74.125.141.103, to your `/etc/hosts` file we could manipulate `ping` into showing whatever we want for it:
```

Add this to `/etc/hosts`:

```
74.125.141.99  blah.blah.com
```

Now repeat our test:

```
$ ping -c1 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.141.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from blah.blah.com (74.125.141.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=109 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 109.886/109.886/109.886/0.000 ms
```

#### Order of /etc/hosts

Keep in mind that the order the hosts are added to `/etc/hosts` can cause the names to show up as you were seeing.

For example if we had this in our `/etc/hosts`:

```
74.125.141.99  blah blah.blah.com
```

The `ping` would show up as you were seeing, with a short name:

```
$ ping -c1 www.google.com
PING www.google.com (74.125.141.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from blah (74.125.141.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=108 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 108.065/108.065/108.065/0.000 ms
```

#### References

- [/etc/resolv.conf order not respected by `ping`](https://serverfault.com/questions/814356/etc-resolv-conf-order-not-respected-by-ping)